Found pigtail after single pole switch to light
Our top floor has two half baths and shared shower with separate entrance. Both half baths have a light/fan combo that with a 14/3, black for light and red for fan (used a blue line in photo for clarity). Also in both half baths, the single pole switch for the light goes into a pigtail, one leading to the black 3-wire and the other complete mystery. Given fan is on 3-wire red, what else could they have expected to turn on with the light? The wire I'm holding is what I removed from the yellow pigtail on switch out so I could trace as dead wire. The trace is also odd because I'm getting beeps just holding it in air anywhere in the bathroom without significant difference in tone. Any thoughts on the mystery wire?

Update: I discovered having only one toner clamp touching a wire introduces a lot of noise, so I put the second clamp on the 3-wire for fan light. Now I could distinguish the tone for the extra run and followed it over to the opposite side of the vanity where it just stopped. So I opened it up and found this  ...I think that's terminated in a clump of drywall mud?


Most device screws/holes are for one wire only.  If joining two hots, one going the switch and one going to something else(a receptacle/outlet), then pigtails should be used.  One screw on the switch is for always hot wire, the other screw is for the switch hot.

@crip659 but this is on the out, so that switch affects two loads on two wires

Are you figuring out hot/not hot with a non-contact voltage tester? Sometimes they false positive. A multimeter would be a better tool. (I’m with the opinion that your pigtail is the incoming hot.) And btw, backstabs are bad to begin with, and those are extra bad for all the exposed copper.

That is possible also.  Two lights/outlets.  A bit more unusual.  Switches do not really concern themselves with out/in, so are you sure it is out or in?

@AloysiusDefenestrate agree on the backstab, all over this house, been replacing as I go. The red nut is definitely the lead as it also feeds the switch to the red wire for the fan, leaving the yellow nut as the load to two separate runs, which I've never seen before

@AloysiusDefenestrate getting 124v between switch leading back to red nut and neutral

Guesses, albeit unlikely: an additional light fixture that has since been hidden. A switched outlet. A light in the attic. Maybe getting a toner and chasing that wire…

Been trying to use a toner, but every time I connect to the wire, even just the black, the whole bathroom picks up tone, even off the walls. I can't distinguish a difference while moving it around given there is always a baseline tone. At first I thought it was the toner, but if I disconnect and lay it down it goes back to expected distance from clips to get tone.

Might have to start cutting holes...

See update... ugh

THe wire you are holding was pigtailed to the hot into the switch. This was done to provide power to another device.
The single black is most likely the switched power to the fan. You just confused the hot into the switch and the switched hot.

The pigtail is hot out of the switch, that is why I can hold it in the picture. Pigtail into the switch is very common, but first time on the out.

Well, I could even touch the copper, not just because I'm only touching the sheathing

The red nut in the photo is the pre-switch pigtail to share the lead. I just realized I didn't say yellow nut pigtail in my original post.

Holding a wire isn’t proof that it’s not hot.

@AloysiusDefenestrate true, has been in the past when accident but not always ☺️ so I'm getting 5v between extra run and pigtailed neutrals
